# Scala symbol to java enum

Tags: java, scala, spray, spray-dsl

I am using a spray-routing which is pretty elegant with using symbols for parameters. However I am dealing with some legacy code and need to use java enum. Is there some elegant way how to convert scala symbol to java enum?

So the desired code would look as follows:

```
      post {
        parameters(('adId.as[String], 'propertyType.as[TypNe])).as(Import) { imp:Import =>
          complete {
            adImporterService ! imp
            StatusCodes.Accepted
          }
        }
```

where TypNem is java enum and Import is a scala case class. Instead of

```
      post {
        parameters(('adId.as[String], 'propertyType.as[String])) { (aId,pType) =>
          complete {
            adImporterService ! Import(aId,TypNe.valueOf(pType.toUpperCase()))
            StatusCodes.Accepted
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: What is your question ? Your two snippets really aren't clear

Comment: is there a possibility to convert scala symbol to java enum directly not via String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java Enum PropertyType

```
public enum PropertyType {
    AAA, BBB, CCC
}
```

You need to provide custom Deserializer

```
  implicit val propertyTypeDeserializer = 
    new Deserializer[String, PropertyType] {
      def apply(s: String): Deserialized[PropertyType] = {
        Try(PropertyType.valueOf(s)) match {
          case Success(pt) => 
             Right(pt)
          case Failure(err) => 
             Left(MalformedContent("Wrong property type. Accepted values: ${PropertyType.values}", Some(err)))
        }
      }
    }

  def receive: Receive = runRoute {
    path("test") {
      parameter('prop.as[PropertyType]) { case prop =>
        get {
          complete(s"Result: $prop. Class: ${prop.getClass}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Solution from @Dici also works and much smaller, but with custom Deserializer you are more flexible with error handling

Comment: I tried to use your approach and seems that I am still missing something in bwtween lines.   parameters(('adId.as[String], 'propertyType.as[TypNemovitosti])).as(Import) { imp =>
              complete {
                adImporterService ! imp
                StatusCodes.Accepted
              }
Getting NPE from spray and RC 500 - internal server error.

Comment: I copy pasted the code and getting NPE for parameter deserialization:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.DeserializerLowerPriorityImplicits$$anon$4.apply(Deserializer.scala:63) ~[spray-httpx_2.10-1.3.2.jar:na] ...

Comment: what is uri that you try to use? looks like you are passing null to serializer

Comment: localhost:8080/test?prop=AAA

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit declaration to improve the readability :

```
implicit def strToTypeNe = TypNe.valueOf(pType.toUpperCase())
```